# test for a valid currency value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a form which has an input for currency.

I want to check the value entered is a valid currency (number only).

valid examples:

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
etc.
1.00
10.00
100.00
1000.00
10000.00
etc
1,000
10,000
etc
1,000.00
10,000.00
etc
```

I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for online, and my regex is weak - how can i do this?

EDIT:

I was going to do a simple replace for ',' and '.' then test if the remainder is a number, however that would validate things like:

```
1,0000,00,000 10.00.00 etc
```

I want to test for a number that a human would recognise. Also, the number shouldn't contain a currency symbol

Comment: Devise a RegEx for the validation.

Comment: So strengthen your knowledge of regular expressions. Spend an hour at http://regexone.com/ and you can probably solve this (and any future regex problems) on your own.

Comment: How about [decimal comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma)? Should that also work?

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex

`/^((\d{0,3}(,\d{3})+)|\d+)(\.\d{2})?$/`

Test cases
http://repl.it/UpC

Answer (score 1):

```
var cur = $("input#currency").val();
if(cur.match(/^\d+$/)) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Yes, ot works ONLY for the first set of examples OP had, the other two would fail when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This Validation function works fine. I found the RegEx in JQuery Validator code.

```
function isValidNum(num) {
    var reg=/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/;
    return reg.test(num) && (num.split(".").length < 3);
}
```

Edit there was a bug, which allowed multiple '.', in the number.

Comment: Valid for `10,000.0000000` also unsure if OP would be satisfied with a minus sign. [Test](http://regex101.com/r/eY2qQ4/1)